# Trying to change color of rows to white

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to change row color to white. Sorry about that

```
Sub Change_Row_Color

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ws.Range("A13:Q299") 
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Card Master")

If ws.rng.Cells.ColorIndex = 4 Then
    rng.Cells.ColorIndex = 1        
End If

End sub
```

Comment: What is not working with your code? First thing I notice is `ws` isn't set an object and `rng` isn't declared as a variable.

Comment: `rng` is already qualified, so you do not include `ws.` before it. Are you getting an error? Or is it changing to the wrong color? Please explain what the problem is.

Comment: It does not clear the color or add white to the rows. It says in the error box "Object  variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Do you want to change the color of row or just from Column A to Q?

Comment: Also, you have to set `ws` to a value BEFORE you use it to set your `rng` object. You are currently doing them in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things

1. You are using the `ws` object before initializing it.
2. Since you want to change it to white, I guess you want `2` instead of `1`?

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Change_Row_Color()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Card Master")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A13:Q299")
    
    With ws
        For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
                If rng.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
                    .Range(rng.Cells(i, 1), rng.Cells(i, 17)).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

To change the color of the entire row and not just `A` to `Q`, change the line

```
.Range(rng.Cells(i, 1), rng.Cells(i, 17)).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
```

to

```
.Rows(rng.Cells(i, 1).Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
```

**NOTE**:

Remember, `White` doesn't mean `No Fill`. If you are trying to remove the color then try this

```
.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
```

instead of

```
.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has inaccuracies as pointed out by others in comments. See below edited code.

```
Sub Change_Row_Color()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngToCheck As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Card Master")
    Set rngToCheck = ws.Range("A13:Q299")
    
    For Each rng In rngToCheck
        If rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks the above code worked like a dream